# How to parse parameters to a hubot script

Tags: regex, coffeescript, hubot

New to hubot/coffeescript and inheriting and existing script.

I googled and found some unhelpful stuff like this: [Hubot matching on multiple tokens per line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673246/hubot-matching-on-multiple-tokens-per-line)

What I want to do is be able to parse parameters to my Hubot message. For example:

```
  startPlaceOrderListener = () ->
    robot.respond /order me (.*)/i, (res) ->
```

and then follow it with what you want to order.

I can obviously re-invent the wheel and parse res.match[1] myself, but hubot already seems to have some regular expression parsing built in for its own use and I was wondering if there's a way to leverage that for my own nefarious purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the coffeescript has regular expressions built in. So

```
/order me (.*)/i
```

is straight coffeescript.

To match a regular expression you can do:

```
/order me (.*)/i.test("Bob")
```

Where the i can be left out if you don't want to ignore case.

Answer (score -1):

To parse the input value in `CoffeeScript` you can do something like:

```
robot.respond /open the (.*) doors/i, (res) ->
  doorType = res.match[1]
  if doorType is "pod bay"
    res.reply "I'm afraid I can't let you do that."
  else
    res.reply "Opening #{doorType} doors"
```